# Shorten If Statement And Making It Less Redundant

Tags: c++, if-statement

New here. I was just wondering if it's possible to make this if statement shorter and less redundant.

```
if (!a && b)
{
    if (c == d && e > 0)
    {
        return;
    }
}
else if (a && !b)
{
    if (c != d)
    {
        return;
    }
}
else if (!a && !b)
{
    return;
}
```

Here's what I've ended up with

```
if ((!a && b && c == d && e > 0) || (a && !b && c != d) || (!a && !b))
{
    return;
}
```

All I did was join nested `if` statements with an `&&` operator, and `if`-`else if` statements with `||` operator. Now I'm stuck, is it possible to make this even shorter? If you could share some tips or your way of approaching this kind of scenario, I'd be glad to hear it out.

Comment: Are you always going to just `return`?

Comment: Sometimes a little verbosity can make code easier to read, understand and most importantly *maintain*. You should still document (comment) the code in either case.

Comment: If you did profile the code, and this is your bottleneck, maybe you should rewrite it to not have any branching at all, but it's not possible to help you with that, as you didn't show what is `a, b, ... e`, and how you set them and how you use them and what is doing the other branch.

Comment: What you did looks good -- but if you really want to be sure you've got the bare-minimum required logic, you should read up on truth-tables (aka Karnaugh maps) and condensing them:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

Comment: Yes I'm always just going to return.

Comment: Then just `return;` without `if`s ... :D

Comment: @Ped7g By the principle of charitable interpretation it is probably a guard clause at the beginning of a longer function.

Comment: @RafałDowgird Yes, that's the case.

Comment: The problem with putting everything on one line is debugging.  If you want to know which condition it is returning on,  jamming everything into one line will not tell you.

Comment: @RafałDowgird most likely. But then the longer function takes probably 98% of execution time, so optimizing guards sounds like bad idea from the clarity/maintenance point of view. But if this is the "meat" of the execution, then it may be worth of optimization, but the first step is to assure your architecture and algorithm is good enough (as you can very likely gain there tenfold+ with the same effort, as would be invested in these `if`), while this has been anonymized and obfuscated to the point where it is pointless to even try to guess, what it does and why.

Comment: Please note that stack overflow isn't for code reviews, that's what codereview.stackexchange.com is for

Comment: Despite what some compilers tell you, you don't need those parentheses around the `&&` expressions. `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so you can write that code as `if (!a && b && c == d && e > 0 || a && !b && c != d || !a && !b)` with less clutter.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of the approaches is readable. It will be better to create a function that indicates the kinds of checks you are performing.

```
if ( !my_very_sensible_special_conditions_are_met(a, b, c, d, e) )
{
   return;
}
```

After that, whether you use the first approach or the second approach in the implementation of the function is less of an issue.

Answer (score 1):

### condition ladder(if,else if) shortening

As you mentioned, in all blocks(if, else if) if you are just having the same set of statements then you can put all the conditions with a single if statement with proper conditions with appropriate brackets.By doing this lines of code will get reduced But you will have some disadvantages as per my point of view

- Readability will get reduced
- In future, if you want to change your code for a particular condition, it will take some time to change.it is not that much easy as you do in condition ladder

if you are not having any problem with the above two points, you can go with your approach itself.But code your conditions as atomic as possible.it will help you out in a long run.

Answer (score 1):

Given the number and complexity of conditions, I'd at least consider making it table driven. For the moment, I've assumed that `a` and `b` are actually ints containing either a `0` or a `1`.

```
int index = a | (b<<1) | (int(c==d)<<2) | (int(e>0) << 3);

static const bool should_return[] = {
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0        
};

if (should_return[index])
    return;
```

The table is still basically incomprehensible, but at least it encodes that incomprehensibility fairly compactly, and makes it easy for the code to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you commented that you are always returning, and since your code does not specify if you do anything else in these `if - else` cases why not do just

```
if (! (a && b) )
{
     return;
}
```

Comment: Because that is not equivalent to the original condition

Comment: Youre right. What was i thinking.. hehe. Where are c, d, e?

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten it a tiny bit further:

```
if (!a && !b || !b && c != d || !a && c==d && e> 0) {
    return;
}
```

But that doesn't increase readability and most likely also not performance. What I would focus on is, what reads most natural with the real variable names.
As a general advice, I'd start with checking the simpler / shorter conditions first. That makes it often more easier to see if you make redundant checks in the following ones.

In any case, as @R.Sahu suggested, a complex condition like that belongs into a separate, named and commented function. If you don't find a good name for it use something generic like e.g. `check_<main_function>_preconditions`.

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I can't resist: If you wan to go overboard, you can make it pretty compact by throwing in a trinary statement:

```
if (!a && !b || c != d ? !b : !a && e> 0) {
    return;
}
```

DON'T do that in production code!